# Mysql query returning too many results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a project where I need to check if the user liked the post and then use `COUNT()` on it, if it gives 0 they haven't if it says 1 they have liked it

I tried using this query

```
SELECT P.id AS id
    , U.username AS username
    , P.body AS body
    , P.timestamp AS timestamp
    , COUNT(L.user_id) AS likes
    , COUNT(LD.post_id) AS liked 
    FROM posts AS P 
    LEFT JOIN users AS U ON U.id = P.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN followers AS F ON F.user_id = 'user1' 
    LEFT JOIN likes AS L ON L.post_id = P.id 
    LEFT JOIN likes AS LD ON LD.post_id = P.id 
        AND LD.user_id = 'user1' 
    WHERE F.following_id = P.user_id 
        OR P.user_id = 'user1' 
    GROUP BY P.id
```

My entrys in my likes table are

```
UserId|PostId|timestamp

user1 |post1 |time

user2 |post1 |time
```

My problem is it keeps giving a 2 for the count of LD which shouldn't be possible

*Note: In my code I use `:user` through PDO I don't actually type the id like that

**Edit:**

```
$sql = "SELECT P.id AS id, P.user_id AS userid, U.username AS username, U.name AS name, U.verified AS verified, P.body AS body, P.data AS data, P.timestamp AS timestamp, P.type AS type, P.users AS users, COUNT(L.user_id) AS likes, COUNT(DISTINCT LD.post_id) AS liked FROM posts AS P LEFT JOIN users AS U ON U.id = P.user_id LEFT JOIN followers AS F ON F.user_id = :userid LEFT JOIN likes AS L ON L.post_id = P.id LEFT JOIN likes AS LD ON LD.post_id = P.id AND LD.user_id = :userid WHERE F.following_id = P.user_id OR P.user_id = :userid GROUP BY P.id";
    $results = DB::query($sql, array(':userid' => $user_id));
```

I then loop through the results and format them into json

Comment: Can you show us sample input for all tables involved, and the expected output?  Your current query is invalid, because you are grouping only by the post `id`, but then selecting other columns which are not aggregates.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited how I run the code in. I also don't really understand what GROUP BY does, should I be including all the ones I am selecting?

Comment: When you tell MySQL `GROUP BY posts.id`, you are saying aggregate together all records belonging to each `id`, and then return something back (e.g. a MAX, an AVG, etc.).  So selecting the username in your query makes no sense.  It just so happens that MySQL tolerates it, with the side effect that it is not clear what your query is trying to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So should I `GROUP BY` everything I'm selecting except for the `COUNT()` methods

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable.  Unless you want aggregates of those other columns, in which case leave as is, but wrap every other column in `MAX`, `AVG`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding a [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) keyword on the `COUNT` function for `liked` column?

```
COUNT(DISTINCT LD.post_id) AS liked
```

Most likely the joins are causing the `likes` table to be duplicated. Thus, we'll only count the unique posts (by `post_id`) using `DISTINCT`.